# Innerblocks isn't adding new blocks when template changes

Tags: block-editor

I have 2 custom blocks, "super-tabs" and "super-tab". Tabs has an inspector control that determines how many tab blocks will be in the tabs block. But when I change the number of tabs, it doesn't change the number of tab blocks. How do I make it do that?

My code looks like this:

```
let defaultChildren = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= numTabs; i++) {
    defaultChildren.push(["super-tabs/super-tab", {}, [["core/paragraph",{content:'Tab'+i}]]]);
}

...

return wp.element.createElement(wp.blockEditor.InnerBlocks, {template: defaultChildren})
```

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the behaviour of the Columns block? You can see how that block does it here: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/columns/edit.js#L85 You just need to ignore the stuff about widths.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks won't be created or removed unless the template is locked.

To lock the template add this argument to the InnerBlocks

```
wp.element.createElement(wp.blockEditor.InnerBlocks, {template: defaultChildren, templateLock: "all"})
```